# How to divide subset of multiple columns in a dataframe with values in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have 2 large dataframes structured as below. I want to divide values in the columns sec1 to sec3  corresponding to variable VA only in the variable column    for each name in df1 by the corresponding values by name in the value column of df2 for each name in df1.

Df1

```
name    variable    year    Sec1    Sec2    Sec3    
CHN VA  1950        23    45    32   
CHN VA  1951        43    45    67    
CHN E   1950        45    67    87    
CHN E   1951    34  53  62    
IND VA  1950    45  56  24
```

DF2

```
name  value    
CHN 3    
IND 6    
MLY 7    
EUR 4
```

The result should be something like

DF1

```
name  variable   year   Sec1    Sec2    Sec3   
CHN VA  1950    23/3    45/3    32/3    
CHN VA  1951    43/3    45/3    67/3    
CHN E   1950    45  67  87    
CHN E   1951    34  53  62   
IND VA  1950    45/6    56/6    24/6
```

I have tried subsetting and  using `cbind()` but am running into problems.

Comment: You say you've run into problems—like what? I'm not sure why you would get errors from using `cbind`, so if there's an issue with data types, it's helpful for us to have the actual data as you're working with it, such as the output of calling `dput` on it

Comment: There was some problem with the data structure, left join was not working on it either but now both cbind and left join are working on it after some adjustments. Answers by grothendeick and akrun have resolved other issues with the dplyr mutate_at code i was trying to use in combination with cbind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Left join `DF1` and `DF2` and then for each `Sec` column divide the row by `value`.  Finally drop the `value` column.

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2, by = "name") %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(variable == "VA", value, 1L)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Sec")), ~ .x / value) %>%
  select(-value)
```

giving:

```
  name variable year      Sec1      Sec2     Sec3
1  CHN       VA 1950  7.666667 15.000000 10.66667
2  CHN       VA 1951 14.333333 15.000000 22.33333
3  CHN        E 1950 45.000000 67.000000 87.00000
4  CHN        E 1951 34.000000 53.000000 62.00000
5  IND       VA 1950  7.500000  9.333333  4.00000
```

**2)** A base R version would be:

```
m <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = "name", all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
ix <- m$variable == "VA"
jx <- grep("^Sec", names(m))
m[ix, jx] <- m[ix, jx] / m$value[ix]
m <- m[names(DF1)]
```

**3)** Another approach is to convert to long form, perform the join and division and convert back. Note that this reorders the rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF1 %>%
  gather(key, val, -name, -variable, -year) %>%
  left_join(DF2, by = "name") %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(variable == "VA", value, 1L)) %>%
  mutate(val = val / value) %>%
  spread(key, val)
```

**4)** If you don't mind writing it out:

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2, by = "name") %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(variable == "VA", value, 1L)) %>%
  mutate(Sec1 = Sec1 / value, Sec2 = Sec2 / value, Sec3 = Sec3 / value, value = NULL)
```

**4a)** or with base R:

```
m <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = "name", all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
m <- transform(m, value = ifelse(variable == "VA", value, 1))
transform(m, Sec1 = Sec1 / value, Sec2 = Sec2 / value, Sec3 = Sec3 / value, value = NULL)
```

### Note

```
Lines1 <- "name variable year Sec1 Sec2 Sec3
CHN VA 1950 23 45 32
CHN VA 1951 43 45 67
CHN E 1950 45 67 87
CHN E 1951 34 53 62
IND VA 1950 45 56 24"
DF1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "name value
CHN 3
IND 6
MLY 7
EUR 4"
DF2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. These work well when i want to transform all values under the variable column , but i just want to transform values in rows corresponding to VA not E in column Variable under columns sec1: sec3. On the lines suggested, Trying something like mutate_at(vars(Sec1:Sec3),  ~ case_when(Variable == 'VA' ~ ./'value', TRUE ~ as.numeric(.))) gives me however an error of non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: Have  added that to all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Using `data.table`** Here  is one option with `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)# v 1.12.4
nm1 <- paste0("Sec", 1:3)
setDT(df1)[df2, (nm1) := lapply(mget(nm1), function(x) 
        fifelse(variable == 'VA', x/value, x)), on = .(name)]
df1
#   name variable year      Sec1      Sec2     Sec3
#1:  CHN       VA 1950  7.666667 15.000000 10.66667
#2:  CHN       VA 1951 14.333333 15.000000 22.33333
#3:  CHN        E 1950 45.000000 67.000000 87.00000
#4:  CHN        E 1951 34.000000 53.000000 62.00000
#5:  IND       VA 1950  7.500000  9.333333  4.00000
```

---

**2) Using `dplyr`**

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Sec')), ~ 
        case_when(variable == 'VA' ~ ./ df2$value[match(name, df2$name)], TRUE ~ .))
#  name variable year      Sec1      Sec2     Sec3
#1  CHN       VA 1950  7.666667 15.000000 10.66667
#2  CHN       VA 1951 14.333333 15.000000 22.33333
#3  CHN        E 1950 45.000000 67.000000 87.00000
#4  CHN        E 1951 34.000000 53.000000 62.00000
#5  IND       VA 1950  7.500000  9.333333  4.00000
```

---

**3) Using base R -match**

```
i1 <- df1$variable == 'VA'
df1[i1, nm1] <- df1[i1,nm1]/with(df1, df2$value[match(name[i1], df2$name)])
df1
#  name variable year      Sec1      Sec2     Sec3
#1  CHN       VA 1950  7.666667 15.000000 10.66667
#2  CHN       VA 1951 14.333333 15.000000 22.33333
#3  CHN        E 1950 45.000000 67.000000 87.00000
#4  CHN        E 1951 34.000000 53.000000 62.00000
#5  IND       VA 1950  7.500000  9.333333  4.00000
```

#### data

```
df1 <-structure(list(name = c("CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "IND"), 
  variable = c("VA", 
 "VA", "E", "E", "VA"), year = c(1950L, 1951L, 1950L, 1951L, 1950L
), Sec1 = c(23, 43, 45, 34, 45), Sec2 = c(45, 45, 67, 53, 56), 
Sec3 = c(32, 67, 87, 62, 24)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(name = c("CHN", "IND", "MLY", "EUR"), value = c(3L, 
 6L, 7L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Again as explained above, the solution i need is just to transform values in columns sec1 : sec3 that correspond to VA not E in column 'Variable ' i.e to a subset of the row values in columns sec1:sec3 corresponding to VA under variable column.

Comment: Well its giving me Error: unexpected ',' in "setDT(df1)[df2, (nm1) := lapply(mget(nm1), function(x)  fifelse(variable == 'VA', x/value, x)), " . Also instead of  using paste i i substituted a vector of actual column names for nm1 since some of them have different names than sec...

Comment: @Shipra I double checked the code.  It is not giving any errors for me.  If you want to use custom names, use that from either the column index or column names i.e. `nm1 <- names(df1)[4:6]`

Comment: @Shipra Can you check the version of `data.table`.  I used `1.12.4` which include `fifelse`

Comment: The version loaded on my R is 1.12.2 . That must be the issue, i shall update and see. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Shipra Yes, that is the issue because you don't have `fifelse`.  If you are using `1.12.2`, change `fifelse` to `ifelse` (but `fifelse` is more efficient)

Comment: Will do that. The Dplyr soln works well too. Thanks a lot!